# How to call item after current item in for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to take a list of phones and convert them into diphones. In practice, this means taking the sequence 's ii z n!' for example, and making 's_ii ii_z z_n!', so for each item, you create a string of the current item, an underscore, and the next item.

I am very unsure as to how you call the next item in a for loop to do this. I was trying to find a way to create a list with the items in a line and then iterating over the range of the list instead so that I could deal with integers but I wasn't sure how I would do this as I would need to iterate over the entire line first.

The phone lists are featured in 'recipe_phone_utts.txt', the format of which is 100,000 lines of sentences which have been translated into phones, usually around 50 phones per line. My initial idea was to create a list which included all words in the line and then use that by joining 'n' and 'n+1' in a for n in line: loop, however I am not sure how to do this.

```
with open('recipe_phone_utts.txt') as file:
    new_diphone_file = open('recipe_diphone_utts.txt', 'a+')
    for line in file:
        current_line = []
        for word in line.split():
            current_line.append(word)
    new_diphone_file.close()
file.close()
```

EDIT: the answers seem to be suggesting I make a list and then use that, however the information is not currently stored in lists and as shown above I do not know how to manually create lists in a loop and then iterate over them.

EDIT 2: one comment asked for sample input and output:

Sample input: s ii z n! cch i k i n w i dh s oo lw t a n d p e p @

Sample output: pau_s s_ii ii_z z_n! !n_cch cch_i i_k k_i i_n n_w w_i i_dh dh_s s_oo oo_lw lw_t t_a a_n n_d d_p p_e e_p p_@ @_pau

the pau_ and _pau at the beginning and end are pauses.

Comment: What have you tried so far? also give us input and expected output.

Comment: Don't be shy, show us what you've tried so far. It is very hard to help you with your question if we don't see input and your desired output.

Comment: it's better if you show your code, sample input and sample output for other people to understandand help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zip` and iterate through the same thing :)

```
>>> x = 's ii z n!'.split()
>>> x
['s', 'ii', 'z', 'n!']
>>> ['_'.join((i,j)) for i,j in zip(x, x[1:])]
['s_ii', 'ii_z', 'z_n!']
```

Comment: `x[:-1]` creates a shallow copy of the array. `zip(x, x[1:])` is the same and saves on performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I forgot to mention in my question and have since edited as such that the first and last phone require being joined with 'pau_' and '_pau' respectively, and I not 100% sure how zip works so do you know how I would be able to do this?

Comment: Really sorry for taking up your time but the file has about 100,000 utterances, do you know of any way to add this into the loop?

The code I am using is a for loop which iterates over lines in the file, does current_line = line.split() and then runs your function using the current_line as x

Comment: I think you may have complicated things as the same result would be given if it were pau at the start and end and the '_'.join was used as before; my problem was writing pau at the start and end of each line and I just realised how that would be pretty easy to do in python so it all works now :)

Comment: Yep. I really did :)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings using the `+` operation. You can split your string into a list, then you can just iterate over your list with a for loop and put it back together with whitespaces inbetween:

```
a = 's ii z n!'.split(' ')
# a = ['s', 'ii', 'z', 'n!']
biList = [a[i]+'_'+a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
# biList = ['s_ii', 'ii_z', 'z_n!']
" ".join(biList)
# output: 's_ii ii_z z_n!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = 's ii z n!'.split(' ')
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    print(*it.chain(x[i-1]+'_', x[i]))
```